# Как правильно создать наследника от QQmlWindow?

Tags: qt5, qml

Мне нужно создать свой класс, наследуемый от QQmlWindow, чтобы в нем можно было ловить ивенты. Как его правильно наследовать?

Мой не рабочий пример:

Создание объекта:

```
CWindow* Window = qobject_cast<CWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
Window->show();
```

CWindow.h

```
#ifndef CWINDOW_H
#define CWINDOW_H

#include <QQuickWindow>

class CWindow : public QQuickWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CWindow(QQuickWindow *parent = nullptr);
    ~CWindow() override;

public:
    void Initialize();

public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // CWINDOW_H
```

CWindow.cpp

```
#include "cwindow.h"

CWindow::CWindow(QQuickWindow *parent)
    : QQuickWindow(parent)
{
}

CWindow::~CWindow()
{

}

void CWindow::Initialize()
{
}

void CWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Pressed";
}

void CWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Moved";
}

void CWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Released";
}
```

Comment: А зачем делать наследника окна QML, чтобы обрабатывать его действия в С++?

Comment: Ага. Нажатия мыши.

Comment: А почему вы не перехватываете эти мыши в qml?

Comment: Если честно, я пробовал. Просто мне нужно переписать перемещение безрамочного окна qml. Я смотрел множества примеров как это сделать в qml. Но не один нормально для меня не работает. Окно перемещается прерываясь или вообще исчезая. В принципе для QQuickWindow я установил фильтр где могу получать нажатия мыши. Но это тоже нормально не работает. Так что я в ступоре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту строчку из main.cpp надо убрать:

```
CWindow* Window = qobject_cast<CWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
Window->show();
```

Далее, вызываете метод регистрации класса в qml (main.cpp полностью):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "CWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Регистрируем наш класс главного окна приложения
    qmlRegisterType<CWindow>("my.windows",1,0,"CWindow");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Теперь создаем главное qml-окно в main.qml (вместо Window, или ApplicationWindow):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import my.windows 1.0 // не забываем эту строчку

CWindow
{
    width: 300
    height: 300;
    visible: true
}
```

Все, теперь вы сможете получать события мыши.

Comment: Спасибо. Только один вопрос, что значиь 'my.' в 'my.windows'?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov Не только my, но и вся эта строчка просто некий (любой) путь к пакету. Вы можете таким образом группировать по-смыслу ваши классы в qml

Comment: А круто. Спасибо)